# error with matrix inverse only when matrix created through script

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

```
A=[ 1   -1  0   0           0           0   0   0   0   0   0   0           0           0   0   0;
    1   -3  1   0           0           0   0   0   0   1   0   0           0           0   0   0;
    0   1   -3  1           0           0   0   0   0   0   1   0           0           0   0   0;
    0   0   1   -7.94E+05   7.94E+05    0   0   0   0   0   0   2           0           0   0   0;
    0   0   0   +7.94E+05   -7.94E+05   1   0   0   0   0   0   0           2           0   0   0;
    0   0   0   0           1           -3  1   0   0   0   0   0           0           1   0   0;
    0   0   0   0           0           1   -3  1   0   0   0   0           0           0   1   0;
    0   0   0   0           0           0   1   -1  0   0   0   0           0           0   0   0;
    0   0   0   0           0           0   0   0   1   -1  0   0           0           0   0   0;
    0   1   0   0           0           0   0   0   1   -3  1   0           0           0   0   0;
    0   0   1   0           0           0   0   0   0   1   -3  1           0           0   0   0;
    0   0   0   2           0           0   0   0   0   0   1   -7.94E+05   7.94E+05    0   0   0;
    0   0   0   0           2           0   0   0   0   0   0   7.94E+05    -7.94E+05   1   0   0;
    0   0   0   0           0           1   0   0   0   0   0   0           1           -3  1   0;
    0   0   0   0           0           0   1   0   0   0   0   0           0           1   -3  1;
    0   0   0   0           0           0   0   0   0   0   0   0           0           0   1   -1];
```

This matrix has an inverse when created manually. But the same matrix when generated through script and inverted gives me "Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate." error and the inverse generated is not the same as `inv(A)`. I tried using the backslash too. I tried creating the matrix through program using format long, short and bank and continue to face the same problem. What could be my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the matrix generated by the script as well?

Comment: Agree with gire - Please post the actual code you used to generate this matrix.  There may be an error in the logic.

Comment: *"I tried creating the matrix through program using format long, short and bank"* - changing the format does not change the precision it only changes the way the numbers are displayed on the screen

Comment: The matrix looks like it should be invertable, it does sound like your script is doing something funny.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The matrix posted above is what is generated by the code.